# Auto Trigger B job after triggering A job in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way that I can auto trigger job B exactly 1 hour after triggering job A, here the issue is job A would have not finished its work in mid of the job itself it has to trigger job B that too exactly after an hour or the other option would be to skip to build script 2 exactly after an hour of execution in script 1 , is there any way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does job A trigger an asynchronuous process or what is the reason A "finishes before it finishes". Or why is it one hour? What is different after that hour?

Comment: A installs a software on a VM but wont return anything (in TC it will be showing running forever) after installation I need to run a batch file , so installation of the software takes an hour and exactly after that I want o run the batch file

Comment: Okei. When and how often, and how foreseeable does A trigger / is A executed?

Comment: Daily minimum 2 times

Comment: When does build configuration A stop running? You said it runs forever - I assume there is something which causes it to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot offer a good practice as a solution, but I can suggest two possible workarounds:

### **1. Build Pause**

You can add a 'Command Line' shell pause as the last build step of project A or the first build step of project B. That pause must be set to one hour:

```
sleep 1h
```

You need to reconfigure the default build timeout for this or the job will fail.

### **2. Strict Scheduling**

If you have some flexibility on the time where A can or should be triggered, you can use the 'Schedule Trigger' to schedule both A and B, e.g. if you schedule project A to 1 pm and project B to 2 pm, you make sure that there is at least one hour between those two. This can be scheduled as often as necessary.

Comment: strict scheduling sounds good , sleep will put lot of pressure on machine

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are proposing is a good way to go about setting up the deployment, but I can think of a few workarounds that might help if you are forced in this direction.

- In configuration A, add build step which adds a scheduled build trigger to configuration B for an hours time (using the API). In configuration B, add a build step to the end of the configuration to remove this scheduled trigger. This feels like a really horrible hack which should be avoided, but [more details here](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003561379-Is-it-possible-to-force-Build-Queue-delay-).
- Outside of TeamCity make use of any pub/sub mechanism so the deployment to the VM can create an event when it has completed. Subscribe to this event and trigger a follow on build using the TeamCity API. For example, if you are using AWS you could have an SNS topic with a lambda function as a subscriber. This lambda function would call the API to queue configuration B when the environment is in a suitable state.

There are probably much nicer solutions if you share what deployment software you are using.